# pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123.dll: Attempt to access invalid address

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame, python-requests

```
music = pygame.mixer.music.load('not.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
```

when executing the code I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Escape it!.py", line 15, in <module>
    music = pygame.mixer.music.load('not.mp3')
pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123.dll: Attempt to access invalid address.
```

I have tried everything from giving full path to only the name but everytime this shows up

Comment: How old is your PyGame library?   Are you usng python2 or Python3 (you've tagged both)?  It's not a coding-solution, but does it work if you audio is converted to another format, say ogg/wav ?

Answer (score 1):

Just close whatever IDE you are using and restart the system. It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Restart your IDE if that doesn't work try restarting your PC it worked for me!!

Comment: I seemed to have gotten the same error after cleaning my Win 10 registry.  I unloaded/loaded pygame and restarted my computer and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Doing following steps maybe solve the problem:

**Step 1**: Go to browser and search download `libmpg123.dll`.

**Step 2**: download `libmpg123.dll` and Extract it.

**Step 3**: After Extract (cut or copy) the two docs and paste in "C:\Windows\System32".

**Step 4**: Installation successfully done.

And this is also works :-

```
music = pygame.mixer.music.load('not.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(loops=-1)
```

Thanks You

Answer (score 1):

All the options given above didn't work for me. So, i uninstalled and reinstalled the "pygame" library from this site. [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame). which worked well.

Comment: Could it be just a side effect of rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

When you newly install the `pygame`, it require system restart.

> Just Restart your PC/Laptop

and then Run the code, it will not throw any error.

The answer of @jrsylvester right, but there is some questions.

1. **Why and when you will get this type of error?**
2. **Why need to restart the pc/laptop?**

Answer :  When you newly installed the `pygame` and execute your code, then it will throw an error.

The system require a reboot to setup their file or code for working environment. so restart your PC/Laptop.

Happy Coding..!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the directory where pygame is installed (you can get it by typing `pip install pygame`).
2. Look for the `libmpg123.dll` in pygame directory.
3. Copy and paste to `C:/windows/system3` and `C:/windows/sysWOW64`.

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to the directory where pygame is installed (you can get it by typing pip install pygame).

2.Look for the libmpg123.dll in pygame directory.

3.Copy and paste to C:/windows/system3 and C:/windows/sysWOW64.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message because I used the version of Python that was installed from the Windows Store.  I reinstalled from official Python and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Surely enough just restarting my IDE or computer didn't help as well as copypasting `libmpg123.dll` to Windows directories or simply reinstalling `pip/pygame`.

I was using Python 3.9 from Microsoft Store. Before giving up and reinstalling Python from Python.org, I downloaded [`pygame‑2.1.2‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) and then run:

```
pip install pygame-2.1.2-pp38-pypy38_pp73-win_amd64.whl
```

This worked perfectly well for me without python reinstallation.

Answer (score -2):

I was under the same problem what i did was simply Install another IDE or just try reinstalling pygame.

Comment: More details is needed. This answer does not contribute as a solution to the mentioned problem by op.

Comment: @rowman funny you say that considering the accepted answer...

Comment: @Tomerikoo yeah you're right, can't remember if I had seen the accepted solution and other answers :)