# Replace from second line onwards

Tags: python

I have a text file, I need to replace its data from second line onwards and write it to fout file having all the lines of input file.

I tried the code

```
fout=open('f2','w')
fin=open('f1','r')
for line in f1:
   
   line=line.replace("()","(n)",1)
   fout.write(line)
```

But I am unable to achieve desired result.

Comment: NameError `f1`, SliceError on `'somebigstringreadfromf1'[2:1]` wich  is empty , NameError on `lines`. What is your problem again? Did you actually run this "code"? Add your stacktrace by [edit]ing your posted code after fixing all problems you can by debugging and researching them yourself

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59623969/pygame-error-failed-loading-libmpg123-dll-attempt-to-access-invalid-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few errors in your code, first of all you are referring to `f1` writing `f1` instead of `fin`. Second thing, you need to read lines from `2` to the end of file.

You can achieve this by reading the fist line (do what you want with it) and then iterate over the rest of the file.

I can't execute this on your file, but something like this could work:

```
fout=open('f2','w')
fin=open('f1','r')
first_line = fin.readline()
fout.write(first_line) #if you want to print that out
for line in fin: #iterate over the rest of the file line by line
    #dothings: no need to fin.read()
    line = line.replace("()","(n)",1)
    fout.write(line)
```

Comment: It was typing mistake.  I corrected it.  I want to replace text from second line. How can I do that

Comment: ```first_line = f.readline()``` here ```f``` is ```fin``` right??

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY Yes! You're right

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with this approach, i tried using seek() but doesnt appear to work as i would expect:

```py
# read content
with open('f1', 'r') as fh:
  f1 = fh.read()

with open('f2', 'r') as fh:
  f2 = fh.read()

# convert to list
f1 = f1.split('\n')
f2 = f2.split('\n')

# modify lists
f1 = [f1[0]]
for line in f2:
  f1.append(line)

f1 = '\n'.join(f1)

# finally write to file
with open('output', 'w') as fh:
  fh.write(f1)
```