# Using Mixer to Play Mp3 Throws Error About libmpg123-0.dll, but There's No Context

Tags: python, audio, pygame, python-3.7, pygame-mixer

I wanted to play a .mp3 file to my microphone using python code that I found in a Stack Overflow post, but I had to do some tweaking with the steps I had to take.

Here are the steps that I had to do:

1. I had to install a program from https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/ what would create a "Virtual Audio Cable" where programs can play music to the input device. However, the program costs money, so I decided to download a separate Virtual Audio Cable from https://vac.muzychenko.net/en/download.htm, which seems good.
2. Next, I had to use the command `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev8` to install that specific version of pygame, but it threw the error: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame==2.0.0.dev8` (following a lot of different versions). So, I decided to use the command `pip install pygame==2.0.0` which worked fine.
3. I then had to go through a series of commands (which can be found in the post) so I can load a .mp3 file to play. However, when I tried to run the command `mixer.music.load("speech.mp3")`, it gave me the error: `pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123-0.dll: The specified module could not be found.` So, i went to https://www.dll-files.com/libmpg123-0.dll.html to download the file that I needed (The second post linked below suggested it), and I moved the contents to `C:\Windows\System32`. Although I downloaded it, I then ran the command again, but it gave me this: `pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123-0.dll:` without any context why something went wrong.

Could someone please give me the correct steps to actually fixing this and getting it working? I have spent nearly three hours now trying to figure out what is wrong.

[Playing mp3 file through microphone with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37055745/playing-mp3-file-through-microphone-with-python)

[pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123.dll: Attempt to access invalid address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59623969/pygame-error-failed-loading-libmpg123-dll-attempt-to-access-invalid-address) (I used this post because it was the only one I could find)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in pygame when installed into Windows Store Python. It was fixed in pygame 2.1.3 by me (https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/3196)

It is also fixed in pygame-ce, a modern fork of pygame, which I would recommend over pygame.

```
pip uninstall pygame
pip install pygame-ce
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion, and I even installed python 3.11 (not from the Microsoft store) and it gave the the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'get_num_audio_devices' from 'pygame._sdl2'` after I installed pygame-ce.

Comment: That was not a stable API, it has been replaced with “get_audio_device_names”. The new function does the count and the names and returns a list of strings instead of bytes, so easier to use all around. https://github.com/pygame-community/pygame-ce/blob/c60d69d8fb12943f6288b4c0d49dc4d21bc295aa/src_c/cython/pygame/_sdl2/audio.pyx#L47